# Integral of a modulus function vs absolute value of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Please refer to the diagram below.
[image]

The diagram shows a curve with equation $y = cos {x\over 2} cos x$, for 0 $\le x$ $\le$ $\pi$, along with the $x$ and $y$-intercepts of the graph.

Question: **By first finding $\int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} \vert cos {x\over 2} cos x \vert\,dx$**, explain why $\vert \int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} cos {x\over 2} cos x \,dx \vert$ is smaller than $\int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} \vert cos {x\over 2} cos x \vert\,dx$. You may refer to the graph provided for assistance.

I have found $\int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} \vert cos {x\over 2} cos x \vert\,dx$ and have done so as shown:
[image]

I then start to calculate $\vert \int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} cos {x\over 2} cos x \,dx \vert$ as shown below.

[image]

Now, I realise I would also end up calculating $\int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} \vert cos {x\over 2} cos x \vert\,dx$ eventually which implies that $\int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} \vert cos {x\over 2} cos x \vert\,dx$ = $\vert \int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} cos {x\over 2} cos x \,dx \vert$? But the question has already stated that $\vert \int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} cos {x\over 2} cos x \,dx \vert$ will be smaller than $\int_{\pi\over 3}^{2\pi\over 3} \vert cos {x\over 2} cos x \vert\,dx$, so I'm not really sure how to proceed from here...

Comment: Think about the cancellation in the areas.  Write the area above the $x$-axis as $A$ and the area below as $B$.  Now, write the two integrals as sums and differences of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\cos\frac{x}{2}\cos x$. Then $f$ has a change of sign at $x=\pi/2$, so
$$
\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}|f(x)|\,dx
=
\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}|f(x)|\,dx
=
\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}f(x)\,dx
-
\int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi/3}f(x)\,dx
$$
On the other hand
$$
\left|\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}|f(x)|\,dx\right|
$$
does not need to be split at the change of sign. If $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, you have
$$
\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}|f(x)|\,dx=
(F(\pi/2)-F(\pi/3))-(F(2\pi/3)-F(\pi/2))=
-F(2\pi/3)-F(\pi/2)+2F(\pi/2)
$$
whereas
$$
\left|\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}|f(x)|\,dx\right|=
|F(2\pi/3)-F(\pi/3)|
$$